# golang decrements of 2 variables in a single line separate by comma, gives error

Tags: go

Hi I am new to golang and I am getting the error for the following piece of code.

I have correct the code by creating 2 statements by why can't I do it in a single statement.

```
for i < j {
// some code
    i--, j-- //error but, I can do i,j = i-1, j-1 
}
```

Please, can some point to a place where I can read more on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because both `i--` and `j--` are statements.

So you either put them on different lines or separate with `;`

References:

- https://golang.org/ref/spec#IncDec_statements
- https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments